# On commutation relations for real scalar free fields in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator

Suppose the creation and annihilation operators are as follow:

$$
a_\mathbf{p} = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg(\sqrt{2\omega_\mathbf{p}} \tilde{\phi}(\mathbf{p}) + i\sqrt{\frac{2}{\omega_\mathbf{p}}} \tilde{\pi}(\mathbf{p}) \Bigg),
$$

$$
a_\mathbf{-p}^\dagger = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg(\sqrt{2\omega_\mathbf{p}} \tilde{\phi}(\mathbf{p}) - i\sqrt{\frac{2}{\omega_\mathbf{p}}} \tilde{\pi}(\mathbf{p}) \Bigg).
$$

I can compute $\left[a_\mathbf{p},a_\mathbf{-p}^\dagger\right]$ but how do I obtain $\left[a_\mathbf{p},a_\mathbf{p}^\dagger\right]$? I think it has something to do with the field being real but I cannot deduce what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Use the reality condition (that is $\phi(x)$ is a real scalar field so that $\phi(x)^\star = \phi(x)$) to figure out what $\phi(-p)$ is, then consider $p \to -p$ in your $a_{-p}^\dagger$ equation. This will give you the answer.